# How do i retrieve all numbers in a string and combine them into one number using regex?

Tags: r, regex

This should be pretty easy, but the results after using suggestions from other SO posts leave me baffled. And, of course, I'd like to avoid using a `For loop`.

**Reproducible example**

```
library(stringr)
input <- "<77Â 500 miles</dd>"
mynumbers <- str_extract_all(input, "[0-9]")
```

The variable **mynumbers** is a list of five characters:

```
> mynumbers
[[1]]
[1] "7" "7" "5" "0" "0"
```

But this is what I'm after:

```
> mynumbers
[1] 77500
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314328/how-to-collapse-a-list-of-characters-into-a-single-string-in-r) suggests using `paste()`, and I guess this should work fine given the correct `sep` and `collapse` arguments, but I have got to be missing something essential here. I have also tried to use `unlist()`. Here is what I've tried so far:

1 - using `paste()`

```
> paste(mynumbers)
[1] "c(\"7\", \"7\", \"5\", \"0\", \"0\")"
```

2 - using `paste()`

```
> paste(mynumbers, sep = " ")
[1] "c(\"7\", \"7\", \"5\", \"0\", \"0\")"
```

3 - using `paste()`

```
> paste (mynumbers, sep = " ", collapse = NULL)
[1] "c(\"7\", \"7\", \"5\", \"0\", \"0\")"
```

4 - using `paste()`

```
> paste (mynumbers, sep = "", collapse = NULL)
[1] "c(\"7\", \"7\", \"5\", \"0\", \"0\")"
```

5 - using `unlist()`

```
> as.numeric(unlist(mynumbers))
[1] 7 7 5 0 0
```

I'm hoping some of you have a few suggestions.
I guess there's an elegant solution using regex somehow, but I'm also very interested in the paste / unlist problem that is specific to R. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract numeric part of strings of mixed numbers and characters in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451251/extract-numeric-part-of-strings-of-mixed-numbers-and-characters-in-r)

Comment: Maybe `as.numeric(paste(str_extract_all(input, "[0-9]", simplify = TRUE), collapse = ""))` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `str_extract_all` returns a `list`.  We need to convert to `vector` and then `paste`.  To extract the `list` element we use `[[` and as there is only a single element, `mynumbers[[1]]` will get the `vector`.  Then, do the `paste/collapse` and `as.numeric`.

```
as.numeric(paste(mynumbers[[1]],collapse=""))
#[1] 77500
```

---

We can also match one or more non-numeric (`\\D+`), replace it with `""` in `gsub` and convert to `numeric`.

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", input))
#[1] 77500
```

Comment: Very useful answer, especially the last part - thank you

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using the stringr library:

```
str_remove_all(input, pattern = "\\D+") %>% as.numeric()
[1] 77500
```